# IOS : how to open a specific page of the Ionic app when I click on a push notification?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an IOS app with Ionic and I use push notifications. 
Is there a way to open a specific page of my Ionic app when I receive a push notification and I click on it ?

Comment: What push notification service, and starter template / basic navigation structure are using?

Comment: I'm using Apple's native push notifications